# Querying an NSDictionary

Tags: ios, key-value

I'm confused about the proper or most efficient way of querying an NSDictionary. I have a mutable array populated by dictionaries. It looks like this...

```
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>title</key>
        <string>entry1</string>
        <key>checkedState</key>
        <string>NO</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>title</key>
        <string>accessoriesImage</string>
        <key>checkedState</key>
        <string>NO</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>title</key>
        <string>activationCharge</string>
        <key>checkedState</key>
        <string>NO</string>
    </dict>
```

Also have a couple of static entries:

```
static NSString *kTitleKey = @"title";
static NSString *kCheckedState = @"checkedState";
```

And what I want to is test for the Title and it's checkedState and then act on that. i.e. if Title = entry1 and it's checkedState = NO then set it's checkedState to YES. Something like this but this is wrong - I know it's wrong - I'm just not getting it.

```
if [([[attributesArray valueForKey:kTitleKey] isEqualToString:@"All"] && [[attributesArray valueForKey:kCheckedState] isEqualToString:@"NO"]) {
[attributesArray setValue:kCheckedState = @"NO" forKey:@"entry1"];
}
```

And yes, I have looked at key-value coding in Apple's docs but I'm not understand. Thus is why I'm here. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(id dict in array /*your original plist is an array for you*/) {
    if([dict[kTitleKey] isEqualTo:@"entry1"]) {
        if([dict[kCheckedKey] isEqualToString:@"YES"]) {
             //process
        }
    }
}
```

**NOTE: this requires that the array contains MUTABLE dictionaries **

** Also: I would make 'checked' into a boolean in your plist... */

Comment: Yes, the dictionary is mutable. And I like your answer however I think that only solves half my issue. I'm trying to test "entry1"'s value for kCheckedState and then act on that. Your solution finds entry1 and then sets the checkedState. See the issue?